# Какой язык использовали в SuperMeatBoy?

Tags: разработка-игр

Собственно, вопрос озвучен в заголовке.

Comment: Судя по иксбоксу - скорее всего сишарп. Что зависит от ответа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++.
Источник - [эта статья от авторов](http://www.supermeatboy.com/134/How_do_I_get_started_programming_games___/), там же немного рассуждают про выбор языка разработки игр. Вкратце: пишите на чем умеете.

Однако если вопрос в том, "на чем пишут чтобы пустили в xbla" вроде есть [дополнительные нюансы](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/626916-developing-games-using-c-for-xbla/)